# Using dotenv with this now doesnt give anything, before it did atleast give

Tags: javascript, nodemailer, dotenv

```
const { google } = require('googleapis');
require('dotenv').config();
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

const oAuth2Client = new google.auth.OAuth2(
  process.env.CLIENT_ID,
  process.env.CLIENT_SECRET,
  process.env.REDIRECT_URI
);
console.log(process.env.CLIENT_ID)
console.log(process.env.CLIENT_SECRET)
console.log(process.env.REDIRECT_URI)
console.log(process.env.REFRESH_TOKEN)
oAuth2Client.setCredentials({ refresh_token: process.env.REFRESH_TOKEN});

const accessToken = await oAuth2Client.getAccessToken();

const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
  service: 'gmail',
  auth: {
    type: 'OAuth2',
    user: process.env.ADDRESS,
    clientId: process.env.CLIENT_ID,
    clientSecret: process.env.CLIENT_SECRET,
    refreshToken: process.env.REFRESH_TOKEN,
    accessToken: accessToken,
  },
});
```

> Main error is that process.env.anything gives undefined, i do have values with the same names as well

I have been working with this issue in many ways, but now i atleast got nodemailer seemingly to work no issue, but now my dotenv isnt working suddenly

Comment: How do you setting these properties in process.env, they are not added actually?

Comment: You can store the dotenv import into a variable and check the `.error` of it. reference - https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv#config

Comment: I found the issue, the issue was you cant actually name the .env file, which i never was told anywhere

Answer (score 0):

Issue was that you cant name a >.env file